# How will I interpret the standard deviation in context?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am not sure how I will interpret the standard deviation (contextual interpretation) in this problem. I think standard deviation is large, so the data points may be more spread from the mean. I just don't know how to interpret using the given problem. Next, the effect of adding 50 to the data set may increase the mean and the standard deviation right? The mean and standard deviation are not resistant to adding, changing or removing any data point, especially if the data point is an outlier.

[image]

Comment: I would probably use the empirical rule, and say that most likely, about 3 of the students' times are between 35 and 55.

Comment: @AdrianKeister is it okay to use the empirical rule even if the problem didn't say whether or not the data set has a normal distribution? It would be helpful if yes.

Comment: The usual rule of thumb is that if you don't have highly skewed data, or outliers, then you're allowed to use the empirical rule, particularly for data like this that you would expect to be normally distributed (or $t$ distributed - but in this case that's probably close enough).